# SQL Server cast hexadecimal time value into readable time format

Tags: sql-server, casting, hex

This is the query for hex value stored in SQL Server:

```
select CAST(0x00EF290000000000 AS Time)
```

Output:

```
02:58:55.0000000
```

I'm converting this hex value into time format in python. But I'm not getting any specification for this hex value structure, like how much byte should I use, is it little-endian or big-indian, how about decimal point value after seconds (02:58:55.xxxxxx).

I got the specification for date, datetime, datetime2 but no luck for time datatype hex value casting. Is there any specification for this hex value for time?? Please help me out, thanks.

Comment: If you have no specification, how do you know your conversion is correct? Where is this hex value coming from? A "hex value" is just a collection of bytes with no intrinsic meaning until someone says how the bytes are to be interpreted -- so what is creating these values? Is your question "given that I know these bytes represent a `TIME`, how do I convert them using Python without using SQL Server", or something else entirely?

Comment: well, the output I've given here is not my conversion, sql server did it. I just want to know how it did it. For example, in datetime hex value casting CAST(0x0000960E0063F510 AS DateTime) first 4 bytes is the number of ticks for date and second 4 bytes for time ticks. So, I need like this specification for Time datatype hex value. And yes, I'm using python, but that's not the issue here. If I know the hex value specification to calculate the tick then any language can find the time format.

Answer (score 1):

The specification for the binary representation of `TIME` can be derived from the [TDS protocol specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523.aspx). Technically speaking, there is no reason for the format used in `CONVERT` to match the TDS specification, but practically speaking the correspondence is pretty reliable.

Section 2.2.5.4.2:

> For TIMENTYPE, the only valid lengths (along with the associated scale
>   value) are:
>
> ```
> SCALE  |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |    6 |    7 |
> LENGTH | 0x03 | 0x03 | 0x04 | 0x04 | 0x05 | 0x05 | 0x05 |
> ```

(Scale 0 is missing for some reason, even though it's valid.)

and 2.2.5.5.1.8:

> **time(n)** is represented as one unsigned integer that represents the number of 10<sup>-*n*</sup> second increments since 12 AM within a
>   day. The length, in bytes, of that integer depends on the scale *n* as
>   follows:
>
> - 3 bytes if 0 <= n <= 2.
> - 4 bytes if 3 <= n <= 4.
> - 5 bytes if 5 <= n <= 7.

Endianness of this integer is little-endian, as specified in 2.2.5.1.

In the example above, the first byte of `0x00EF290000000000` is the scale (0) that specifies the remaining length (3 bytes), meaning the unsigned integer `0xef2900` in little-endian representing the number of 10<sup>-0</sup> second increments. `29ef` hex is 10735, and 10735 seconds past midnight is indeed 02:58:55. Because you are converting to `TIME` (which is `TIME(7)` without an explicit scale) this is displayed with 7 digits of precision for the fractional part, even though they were not present in the input.

I hope the above shows that you are far better off converting `TIME` between a string and back than to mess around with the binary representation, regardless of your language. `02:58:55` can be parsed by any language and framework I know and will remain reliable across versions of SQL Server. Conversely, converting `01:23:45.6789012` to `0x0714BE89B30B` is a lot more involved. Unless you're implementing a TDS parser, I can't think of any scenario where you would want to convert the binary representations of values *outside* SQL Server.

Sample C# code to convert the binary value to 100 ns ticks:

```cs
var timeBinary = new byte[] { 0x00, 0xEF, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
var lengths = new byte[] { 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x04, 0x04, 0x05, 0x05, 0x05 };
int scale = timeBinary[0];
int length = lengths[scale];
long ticksValue = 0;
for (int i = length; i > 0; --i) {
    ticksValue = ticksValue * 256 + timeBinary[i];
}
long scaleFactor = 10000000; // 10^7
for (int i = 0; i < scale; ++i) {
    scaleFactor /= 10;
}
var ticks = ticksValue * scaleFactor;
var time = TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticks);
```

Validating the input is omitted in this code. It's only intended to demonstrate the logic (and should be easy enough to translate to other languages); don't use it as-is in production.